# Firestore onSnapshot() returns null

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I have this code :

```
 firestore()
    .collection('messages')
    .where('conversationString', '==', convString)
    .where('timestamp', '>', maxTimestamp).onSnapshot(onUpdate);
```

The problem is onUpdate's parameter is null.

```
const onUpdate = async results => {
    // results is null
};
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. What are the values of `convString` and `maxTimestamp` inside your reference?

Comment: What is `firestore()`? Can you show how you declare it and how you initialize the Firebase JS SDK? First thought is that you should do `firebase.firestore().collection('messages')...`. Also, note that the `results` function is not asynchronous, see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#onsnapshot).

Comment: @RenaudTarnec The `react-native-firebase` libraries use a separate top-level namespace for each product, so when using that  https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage`firestore()` is the equivalent on `firebase.firestore()` in other places. See https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage

Comment: Please also add a `.catch((e)=>{ console.log(e) })` block, you might be missing an index.

Comment: Can anyone tell me if it is possible to nest .where ?  I  never had used . where method twice so....

Comment: Thanks for the explanations on the `react-native-firebase` libraries Frank! @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The snapshot listener takes two arguments: first the snapshots, second any errors. Only one of these arguments will have a value. So most likely you are getting an error from the SDK.

I highly recommend keeping the [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage#realtime-changes) handy, and using the examples in there as the basis for your code. From there:

```
function onResult(QuerySnapshot) {
  console.log('Got Users collection result.');
}

function onError(error) {
  console.error(error);
}

firestore().collection('Users').onSnapshot(onResult, onError);
```